# Existence of a zero point for a derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Could you please check correctness of my proof.

**Statement**

$a,b \in \mathbb R$, $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function, $f'(a)>0, f'(b)<0$, then $\exists \xi \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$.

**Proof**

$f$ is differentiable, thus continuous, thus the set $f([a,b])$ is a compact interval, so we define $[c,d]:=f([a,b]), c,d \in \mathbb R$.

So $\exists \xi \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\xi)=d$, in other words in $\xi$ the function achieves the global maximum $d$ on $[a,b]$.

We show that $f(a)\ne d$ and $f(b) \ne d$. Indeed, $$f'(a)>0 \implies \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} > 0 \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(a+1/n)-f(a)}{1/n} > 0 \implies \exists N \in \mathbb N: \frac{f(a+1/N)-f(a)}{1/N} > 0 \implies f(a+1/N)>f(a)$$

Thus $f(a)$ can not be the global maximum. Analogously one can proof that $f(b) \ne d$.

So we conclude that $\xi \in (a,b)$ and $f$ achieves in $\xi$ the global maximum. It implies that $f'(\xi)=0$. Q.E.D.

Comment: You're almost there but you haven't shown that the derivative is continuous.  Consider the function y=|x|

Comment: @lordoftheshadows He didn't use continuity of the derivative.

Comment: This proof is correct. Good job. It might be worth noting that the theorem statement is similar to Rolle's theorem, except the additional assumptions that $f'(a)>0$ and $f'(b)<0$ eliminate all the possibilities other than in $\xi\in (a,b)$.

Comment: So this is the "derivative" version of the intermediate value theorem. In intermediate value theorem, we need to assume that $f(x)$ is continuous. For derivatives it seems that this is not required, provided it is differentiable?

Comment: @Mathaholic yes, correct.

Comment: This is Darboux's theorem

Comment: How do you define the derivative at the boundary points of the interval?

Comment: @ThorbenKastenholz The same way as for any other point in the interval: $f'(a)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(a) - f(x_n)}{a - x_n}, \forall x_n \to a, x_n \in (a,b] \forall n \in \mathbb N$